# Scala lift type mismatch?

Tags: scala, lift, mismatch

I am programming a webapp at the moment and I want to use a value from a submit form but get a type mismatch:

type mismatch; found : connectfour.Board=> Option[Int] required: () => Any

My code looks like this:

```
var value=0
 "name=value" #> SHtml.onSubmit(s => asInt(s).foreach(value= _)) &
 // when the form is submitted, process the variable
"type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(askForHumanMove)
```

and my askForHumanMove method:

```
def askForHumanMove(board: connectfour.Board): Option[Int] = {
    Some(value)        
}
```

Hope somebody can help me with this type mismatch.

Thank you!

Best regards,
John

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me that `onSubmitUnit` accepts a `() => Any` as a parameter. But you are passing a method which is being lifted into a function `Board => Option[Int]`. These types are not compatible.

Do you have the relevant instance of `Board` in scope at the point of calling the `onSubmitUnit` method? If so, the fix is simple:

```
"type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit( () => askForHumanMove(board) )
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply! okay, I've got this now in my render method, and it look good! but how can I use the variable value in my askForHumanMove method?